# How to decorate a Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

I want to tag each element of a tree with a different value (Int, for example sake). I managed to do this but the code is ugly as a beast and I don't know how to work with Monads yet.

My take:

```
data Tree a = Tree (a, [Tree a])

tag (Tree (x, l)) n = ((m, x), l')
 where (m,l') = foldl g (n,[]) l
        where g (n,r) x = let ff = tag x n in ((fst $ fst ff) +1, (Tree ff):r)
```

Do you know some better way?

**EDIT:**
I just realized that the above foldl really is mapAccumL. So, here is a cleaned version of the above:

```
import Data.List (mapAccumL)

data Tree a = Tree (a, [Tree a])

tag (Tree (x, l)) n = ((m,x),l')
  where (m,l') = mapAccumL g n l
        g n x  = let ff@((f,_),_) = tag x n in (f+1,ff)
```

Comment: Note that mapAccumL is the same as mapM for the state monad, if you remove the newtypes.  So whenever you use mapAccumL, consider using the state monad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've modified your types slightly.  Study this code carefully:

```
import Control.Monad.State

-- It's better not to use a pair as the argument of the constructor    
data Tree a = Tree a [Tree a] deriving Show

-- We typically want to put the Tree argument last; it makes it
-- easier to compose tree functions.  
--
-- Also, the Enum class is what you want here instead of numbers; 
-- you want a "give me the next tag" operation, which is the succ
-- method from Enum.  (For Int, succ is (+1).)
tag :: Enum t => t -> Tree a -> Tree (a, t)
tag init tree = 
    -- tagStep is where the action happens.  This just gets the ball
    -- rolling.
    evalState (tagStep tree) init

-- This is one monadic "step" of the calculation.  It assumes that
-- it has access to the current tag value implicitcly.  I'll 
-- annotate it in the comments.
tagStep :: Enum t => Tree a -> State t (Tree (a, t))
tagStep (Tree a subtrees) = 
    do -- First, recurse into the subtrees.  mapM is a utility function
       -- for executing a monadic action (like tagStep) on a list of
       -- elements, and producing the list of results.
       subtrees' <- mapM tagStep subtrees  

       -- The monadic action "get" accesses the implicit state parameter
       -- in the State monad.  The variable tag gets the value.
       tag <- get 

       -- The monadic action `put` sets the implicit state parameter in
       -- the State monad.  The next get will see the value of succ tag
       -- (assuming no other puts in between).
       --
       -- Note that when we did mapM tagStep subtrees above, this will 
       -- have executed a get and a put (succ tag) for each subtree.           
       put (succ tag)

       return $ Tree (a, tag) subtrees'
```

---

**EDIT:** Same solution as above, but put through one round of refactoring into reusable pieces:

```
-- This function is not part of the solution, but it will help you 
-- understand mapTreeM below.
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapTree fn (Tree a subtrees) = 
    let subtrees' = map (mapTree fn) subtrees
        a' = fn a
     in Tree a' subtrees'

-- Normally you'd write that function like this:
mapTree' fn (Tree a subtrees) = Tree (fn a) $ map (mapTree' fn) subtrees

-- But I wrote it out the long way to bring out the similarity to the 
-- following, which extracts the structure of the tagStep definition from 
-- the first solution above.    
mapTreeM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> Tree a -> m (Tree b)
mapTreeM action (Tree a subtrees) =
    do subtrees' <- mapM (mapTreeM action) subtrees
       a' <- action a
       return $ Tree a' subtrees'

-- That whole business with getting the state and putting the successor
-- in as the replacement can be abstracted out.  This action is like a 
-- post-increment operator.    
postIncrement :: Enum s => State s s
postIncrement = do val <- get
                   put (succ val)
                   return val

-- Now tag can be easily written in terms of those.
tag init tree = evalState (mapTreeM step tree) init
    where step a = do tag <- postIncrement
                      return (a, tag)
```

You can make `mapTreeM` process the local value before the subtrees if you want:

```
mapTreeM action (Tree a subtrees) =
    do a' <- action a
       subtrees' <- mapM (mapTreeM action) subtrees
       return $ Tree a' subtrees'
```

And using `Control.Monad` you can turn this into a one-liner:

```
mapTreeM action (Tree a subtrees) =
    -- Apply the Tree constructor to the results of the two actions
    liftM2 Tree (action a) (mapM (mapTreeM action) subtrees)

-- in the children-first order:
mapTreeM' action (Tree a subtrees) =
    liftM2 (flip Tree) (mapM (mapTreeM action) subtrees) (action a)
```

Comment: I've been told that Monads really help when we're doing imperative stuff, but I never imagined it would be so easy on the eyes. Thanks for a most comprehensive answer involving monads. (I need to first study them in general to understand their rational and uses)

Answer (score 17):

Taking advantage of `Data.Traversable` and some useful GHC extensions, we can refactor [sacundim's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12658639/98117) further:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable

data Tree a = Tree a [Tree a]
  deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

postIncrement :: Enum s => State s s
postIncrement = do val <- get
                   put (succ val)
                   return val

-- Works for any Traversable, not just trees!
tag :: (Enum s, Traversable t) => s -> t a -> t (a, s)
tag init tree = evalState (traverse step tree) init
    where step a = do tag <- postIncrement
                      return (a, tag)
```