# How would I use lens in Haskell to duplicate Python's enumerate?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Python's [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) on lists can be written as `zip [0..]`. I looked at Control.Lens.Traversal and Control.Lens.Indexed, but I couldn't figure out how to use lenses to generalize this to any reasonable container (I hesitate to say "Traversable").

I'm guessing `itraverse` or `itraverseOf` is key.

Comment: I believe `lens` offers an indexed map, but I'm not sure. I know that if you're using `Data.Sequence`, it's far more efficient to use `mapWithIndex (,)` than any sort of traversal.

Comment: `itraverse` certainly does what you want.  What difficulty are you having using it?

Comment: @Carl My naive intuition of `itraverse (,) "abcd"` complains about a lack of a monoid instance for Int. It also looks like using `(,)` as the first argument gives me the wrong output type, namely `(Int, t a)` rather than `t (Int, a)`.

Comment: @AlexR Well, yes. `traverse` and `itraverse` work in an `Applicative` context, which you're ignoring. Try something like `imap f = runIdentity . itraverse (\i a -> return (f i a))`.

Comment: Dunno about lens, but this is fundamentally the same problem as discussed in ["How to decorate a Tree in Haskell"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658443/how-to-decorate-a-tree-in-haskell/12658639).  [The answer by hammar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12662925/1094403) is the same as [bhelkir's response to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29125450/1094403).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using a container that is an instance of `FunctorWithIndex` then you can simply use `imap (,)`:

```
> imap (,) "abc"
[(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]
```

But if the index isn't the position this won't work:

```
> let m = Map.fromList [('a', "foo"), ('b', "bar"), ('c', "foobar")])
> imap (,) m
fromList [('a',('a',"foo")),('b',('b',"bar")),('c',('c',"foobar"))]
```

Instead you can use `traversed`, which is an indexed traversal where the index is the order the elements appear. This can be used for anything that's `Traversable`. Instead of `imap` use `iover traversed` (which is the same as `imapOf` but that's been deprecated):

```
> iover traversed (,) "abc"
[(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]

> iover traversed (,) m
fromList [('a',(0,"foo")),('b',(1,"bar")),('c',(2,"foobar"))]
```

Answer (score 6):

One solution would be to use the `State` monad with `traverse`, since it is also `Applicative`:

```
enumerate :: (Integral n, Traversable t) => t a -> t (n, a)
enumerate t = evalState (traverse go t) 0
    where
        go a = do
            i <- get
            modify (+1)
            return (i, a)
```

Comment: In an `Applicative` style, by the way, `go a = (\i -> (i,a)) <$> get <* modify (+1)`. May I suggest `(Traversable t, Integral n) => t a -> t (n, a)`?

Comment: @dfeuer Sure, I was just being lazy.  You could even relax it further to `Num` if you really wanted.

Comment: That's the solution I'd probably use normally (well, looking at my code, it more closely resembles @dfeuer modification, except using tuple sections and `succ`. I'm looking for a Lens-specific answer, though, in part to expand my understanding of the package.

Comment: @AlexR, I avoided tuple sections just because they're not standard; I'd use them too. You're right that using `Enum` makes a lot of sense, but `Enum` is a terrible, horrible, no good, very bad class :-/

Answer (score 3):

You're ignoring the `Applicative` context on `itraverse`. You need *something* for it to be working with.  But the something can be boring, like `Identity`.

```
imap f = runIdentity . itraverse (\i a -> return (f i a))
```

And then you get what you're looking for:

```
> imap (,) [1,2,3]
[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]
```

Comment: Ah, there are more handy things available, like the ones in cchalmer's answer.