# Get indices of Applicative Traversable without dummy

Tags: haskell, applicative, traversable

Let's say I have some `v`, which is both `Applicative` and also `Traversable`. How can I get a `v` with the indices of `v`? For a concrete example, consider `V3` from `Linear`. I want `V3 0 1 2`.

One way is to use `mapAccumL` with a dummy, for example:

```
snd $ T.mapAccumL 
    (\idx _ -> (idx + 1, idx)) 
    0 (pure "") :: V3 Int
```

But the `(pure "")` dummy feels inelegant. How can we do this in a more elegant way?

Comment: Relevant: [How would I use `lens` in Haskell to duplicate Python's `enumerate`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125149/how-would-i-use-lens-in-haskell-to-duplicate-pythons-enumerate)

Comment: What's the deal with the empty string? If you want a "nothing interesting" value, the canonical choice is `()`.

Comment: The post @dfeuer linked contains several nice alternative approaches, but none of them remove the need for an initial value to give the shape. (But then that question didn't ask for that, either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not going to escape using `pure` if you are doing this with just `Applicative` and `Traversable`. It's the only function in those classes which gives you a value of your type without already *having* one.

Also, your dummy determines the shape of the value you construct. Consider a type such as lists, where not all values have the same shape: How do you choose between constructing `[0]`, `[0,1]` or `[0,1,2]`? (A `pure`-based dummy gives you the first one.)