# Index contents of a list ([a] -> [(Int, a)])

Tags: haskell, monads

I want a function that takes in a list and indexes out all the contents: `indexed :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]`. Or the returned value can be whatever Monad as long as it contains indexed values of the original list.

I thought that I would need StateT to temporary remember and inclement index numbers while processing each element, but I'm not familiar with Monad transformer thingy and I need some help write the function.

I believe it will look similar to this (this is sure not working):

```
indexed ns = do
  n <- ns
  i <- get
  put (i + 1)
  return (i, n)
```

How would you write it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658443/how-to-decorate-a-tree-in-haskell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to go to all that trouble.

```
indexed = zip [0..]
```

If you want to use monad transformers, I think there’s this:

```
indexed :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
indexed ns = evalState (runListT lt) 0 where
    lt = do
        n <- ListT $ return ns
        i <- get <* modify (+1)
        return (i, n)
```

Comment: Haha that's clever! Thanks for your answer. But I'm still wondering how it could be implemented within Monad transformer.

Comment: @RyoichiroOka There's different ways to do that in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125149/how-would-i-use-lens-in-haskell-to-duplicate-pythons-enumerate).

Comment: @RyoichiroOka, just clearing up in case you have a mistake in your mind: `zip [0..]` is not some clever hack that works in this case where in general you need a state transformer; rather, state is almost never necessary and most problems can be solved by combining standard functions.  State really should be one of your last resorts.